# Simple use of mouse clicks to position a ball

Tags: javascript, game, html5, canvas

Here's a simple program I wrote to teach myself the basics of using a mouse for a potential HTML5/JavaScript game. The thing that tripped me up was `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` don't return the correct values as they stand. One has to get the offsets of the canvas object, which in turn may be a child object of other objects whose offsets need to be obtained...

I found this a bit counter intuitive. If anyone has more elegant solutions, I'd be interested to learn about them.

```js
var canvas, context, ball_pos;

var BALL_RADIUS = 15;

function start() {
    'use strict';
    canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ball_pos = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2];
}

function draw() {
    'use strict';

    // draw background
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(248,248,248)"; // off white
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw ball
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball_pos[0], ball_pos[1], BALL_RADIUS, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}

function animate() {
    'use strict';
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    draw();
}

function click(evt) {
    'use strict';
    var offset = [0, 0],
        obj = canvas;
    while (obj.offsetParent !== null) {
        offset[0] += obj.offsetLeft;
        offset[1] += obj.offsetTop;
        obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }
    ball_pos[0] = evt.clientX - offset[0];
    ball_pos[1] = evt.clientY - offset[1];
}

// register event handlers
window.onclick = click;

start();
animate();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the bounding rectangle for a canvas. Consider:

```
function click(evt) {
    'use strict';
    var bound = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    ball_pos[0] = evt.clientX - bound.left;
    ball_pos[1] = evt.clientY - bound.top;
}
```

This should help you to avoid walking up the stack of objects to find the relative position.

See it working here:

```js
var canvas, context, ball_pos;

var BALL_RADIUS = 15;

function start() {
    'use strict';
    canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ball_pos = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2];
}

function draw() {
    'use strict';

    // draw background
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(248,248,248)"; // off white
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw ball
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball_pos[0], ball_pos[1], BALL_RADIUS, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}

function animate() {
    'use strict';
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    draw();
}

function click(evt) {
    'use strict';
    var bound = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    ball_pos[0] = evt.clientX - bound.left;
    ball_pos[1] = evt.clientY - bound.top;
}

// register event handlers
window.onclick = click;

start();
animate();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks much simpler than looping to the root object.